# Open PDF file in new tab using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have a button on my page, labeled `View PDF`. The button does 2 jobs:

1. creates a PDF file programatically and stores it on the server with the name `tmp.pdf`.
2. opens the `tmp.pdf` in a new tab and does not cause a postback on the current tab (I guess I must write a javascript function with the path of the `tmp.pdf` as the parameter)

I've completed the first job but I still don't get how the second job can be done.

Please note that the opened tab contains the pdf only (the browser supports pdf file), not another ASP page. Please help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

on your button click - open in a new tab your asp page which:

1. creates the tmp.pdf,
2. makes redirect to the page which shows that pdf (Response.Redirect("~/tmp.pdf");) -if user reload the page // - there is no new pdf will be created